# Can we make a replacement for the atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere

Let's say you are a scientist in the future trying to save the world that started to crumble down because our atmosphere is slowly vanishing. To save the world you have to make a "new atmosphere". Can it be done? And if it can, how?

Comment: How is the atmosphere being depleted?

Comment: @DJMethaneMan I haven't really thought about it, but it has something to do with environmental damage.

Comment: It's important to know why and how it got depleted in the first place, since this will affect the answer.

Comment: Suggestion: Solar wind. You could either vamp the Sun's output up a lot or you could somehow weaken the magnetic field.

Comment: Also, by "slowly vanishing" what do you mean? If it is happening fast enough to cause damage and societal collapse, then it is not really happening "slowly" in the grand scale of things. If it happens slow on a cosmological scale I get the feeling we wouldn't notice it for many generations.

Comment: What tech do they have? You say 'future' but that is a very broad term....how far in the future. Sorry for being nit-picky, but if you want a good answer you have to give us more to work with than "the atmosphere is disappearing, how do I stop it?".

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Thank you for your answer, and for the suggestions too. I haven't really thought about the detail because it's still a rough idea on my head. I'll try to be more specific next time, Thank you.

Comment: @Lohoris I didn't know that, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I think you need to resolve the root cause of the depleting atmosphere issue first then we can think how to top up with new air

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what rate the atmosphere is depleting. This depends on how. If a solar flare is destroying the atmosphere, it should be some time before it is gone. Think millions of years. If it is something man-made, then we should start by stoping whatever we are doing that is depleting the atmosphere.

If we have achieved easy space travel (through the solar system, maybe not interstellar) we could have shipments of gasses from the gas giants to add to the atmosphere. Yes, it could in theory be that simple. In practice it would be **very** difficult, if not impossible.

If the atmosphere should be gone in a single lifetime (and that is an unrealistically fast pace) then there is no way to replenish it. We would have to totally reverse whatever natural or man-made processes that caused the disaster. That would likely be the equivalent of trying to reverse global warming, or make a hurricane turn tail and head in the opposite direction.